# Can I access windows services on a client server from a handheld scanner or from my desktop PC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a small program (C# Windows Form) that will access the printer services and print a barcode label. This program only works when I install it and run it on the clients server. When I try running it from my PC I get an error.

Here is what I have:

```
public static bool PrintBin(string trans, string qty)
{

    string m1    = string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", trans, qty, PrinterName, ConnString);
    string m2    = string.Empty;
    bool  status = true;

    try
    {
        TcpClient tcpSocket = new TcpClient(PrinterServer, 65000);
        NetworkStream streamToServer = tcpSocket.GetStream();

        // create a streamWriter and use it to write a string to the server
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = 
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(streamToServer);
        writer.WriteLine(m1); 
        writer.Flush();

        // Read response
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = 
            new System.IO.StreamReader(streamToServer);
        m2 = reader.ReadLine();

        streamToServer.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        m2 = "Can not find scanner printing service.";
        status = false;
    }
```

It gets stuck and errors out on the TcpClient line.

Thank you

*** UPDATE ***

Here is the error message i get:

"A connection attemp failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because a connected host has failed to respond 172.18.10.22:65000 at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient (String hostname, Int32 port)"

Thanks

Comment: Show the exception. "errors out" is largely useless. Most likely though you can't connect to the IP address.

Comment: Start by troubleshooting the network: firewall, port forwarding etc...Not much here programming related.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I add the error to my post if that helps at all.

Comment: Can you ping  that IP address?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes I can and I can connect to it from remote desktop. I think the problem is when it connects to the server it runs  a windows print service and thats where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Sounds like the firewall on the remote box is blocking that port.